# Is there any command which can show what kinds of function are in-built in pandas or matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Since I don't have pure knowledge of the pandas library, I just want to explore the range of functions that pandas library offers to users.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dir(pandas)`

But you'd better go to the official documentation.